# return custom query select in activerecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I've got a query that does some math and returns a calculated custom select field with the result set. I cannot figure out how to access that in the activerecord object that is returned. I've added an attr_accessor for it also.

```
attr_accessor :percentage_used

select('gateways.*, (num_transactions_today/ SUM(num_transactions_today)) AS percentage_used ').joins(:gateway_groups).where('map_gateway_groups.gateway_group_id = ?', gateway_group_id)
```

in the result set, I would expect to have access to :percentage_used, but it is not in there. Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong? i've never needed to do this before.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can access it as

```
object["percentage_used"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You neither need nor want `attr_accessor` for that. `attr_accessor` creates an instance variable, an accessor method for getting the value of that instance variable, and a mutator method for changing its value. When you say this:

```
select('gateways.*, (num_transactions_today/ SUM(num_transactions_today)) AS percentage_used ...
```

ActiveRecord will automatically add a `percentage_used` method to the returned objects. But the `percentage_used` method for accessing that value will be added by `method_missing`. Since you've said `attr_accessor :percentage_used`, `method_missing` will never be called and you can't get at the `percentage_used` value from the query in the usual way.

If you drop the `attr_accessor :percentage_used`, then you'll be able to call `percentage_used` on objects returned by that `select` and you'll find the values you're looking for. However, AR won't be able to convert the value to a native Ruby number though so you'll have to `to_f` the returned string yourself.